# Spark 2.0 as Technical Preview in HortonWorks Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

We are planning to use `HortonWorks` Cluster for our upcoming project.

I can see from HortonWorks web site `Spark 1.6.2` is fully supported version and Spark 2.0 is Technical Preview.

What does Technical Preview mean? can we use this for development and Production jobs?

Comment: Why not deploy Spark 2 on your own? The only disadvantage means it's not supported if you file a  ticket with Hortonworks

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you are stricly reduced to the Horton works HDP 2.5 version. The freshly relesed Spark 2.0.0 was introduced in july, 2016 in the technical preview of the 2.5.0.

It's not a good idea to put it in production (the .0 effect). But, in the HDP 2.5.3 the 2.0.1 version of Spark was released in technical preview. I think that you must use this version.

Anyway, if you can upgrade to the HPD 2.6, don't hesitate to do it, there is Spark 2.1.0 in the bundle.